# Highcharts Dynamic update pie Chart mysql

Tags: mysql, dynamic, charts, highcharts

I have an pie and I want to add dynamic update every 3 sec from mysql data.php.I need to add events in .ready(function() ?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
            $(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false,
                backgroundColor:'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.0)'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Grafic'
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                },},
            credits: {
            enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage.toFixed(4) +' %';}}}},
            series: [{
                type: 'pie',
                data: []}]}
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series[0].data = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

Comment: A post from a few years ago may help. 

[Dynamic Data Series to High Charts][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682484/adding-dynamic-data-series-to-high-charts/10693975#10693975

Comment: You need to catch load event like [here](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update), call ajax and  use [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) to manipulate value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

You will probably want to use "setinterval".

You may also need to set up a recursive callback so it updates highcharts every time.

Let me know if you  have any questions.

***UPDATE 09/29/2016***

Here is another way,  with a recursive settimeout in jQuery, in case it helps.

```
(function($){

    $(function(){  //document.ready

    });

    (function recurseEvent(element){

            element.doStuff();

            setTimeout(function(){
                recurseEvent(element);
            }, 2000);

    })($('#myElement'));

})(jQuery);`
```